# HTTP call from a Logic App that requires digest authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, hash, azure-logic-apps

I'm integrating services using Azure logic apps. One of the flows requires calls from within the Logic Apps towards a HTTP endpoint that requires digest authentication.

It works as follows using curl:

```
curl --digest --user "XX:YY" http://<URI>
```

However, [Logic Apps do not seem to support digest authentication](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/36118702-support-http-digest-authentication).

Is there any way around this?
Is there any way to call a curl request from Azure Logic Apps? Maybe through a function?

Comment: well, a work around would be to call something else that would in turn call the desired service and return the answer to the Logic App.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, currently digest authentication is not supported in logic app. As you mentioned, we can use [azure function in logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#create-functions-inside-logic-apps) and transfer the url as a parameter to the function. In function, you can refer to the code below to implement digest authentication.

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
credentialCache.Add(
  new Uri(url), // request url
  "Digest", // authentication type
  new NetworkCredential("user", "password") // credentials
);

request.Credentials = credentialCache;
```